Electron: File paths with special characters display incorrectly (e.g., 'é' and '–') when selected in dialog
I'm working on an Electron application where users can select files through a dialog.showOpenDialog. The selected file paths are logged and processed, but file paths containing special characters (e.g., é, –) appear incorrectly in the logs and processing. Here's an example of the issue:
The file path I select:
E:\m\upload\Casselberry-DuPreé – City Down\B2 - War.flac

The filepath my electron app saves:
E:\m\upload\Casselberry-DuPre├⌐ ΓÇô City Down\B2 - War.flac

I have tried multiple different sanitization issues but my issue persists, is there a good npm solution, ideally without importing a package, for getting the path correctly? Why Is electron malforming it?
My code:
ipcMain.on('open-file-dialog', async (event) => {
  try {
    const result = await dialog.showOpenDialog({
      properties: ['openFile', 'multiSelections']
    });

    if (!result.canceled && result.filePaths.length > 0) {
      const fileInfoArray = await Promise.all(
        result.filePaths.map(async (filePath) => {
          // Normalize and decode file path to handle special characters
          const normalizedPath = path.resolve(filePath);
          console.log('normalizedPath = ', normalizedPath);

          // Decode using iconv-lite to handle special characters
          const decodedPath = iconv.decode(Buffer.from(normalizedPath, 'binary'), 'utf-8');
          console.log('decodedPath = ', decodedPath);

          const ext = path.extname(decodedPath).toLowerCase().substring(1); // Extract extension without the dot
          let fileType = 'other'; // Default file type
          let dimensions = null;

          if (audioExtensions.includes(ext)) {
            fileType = 'audio';
          } else if (imageExtensions.includes(ext)) {
            fileType = 'image';
            try {
              const metadata = await sharp(decodedPath).metadata();
              dimensions = `${metadata.width}x${metadata.height}`;
            } catch (error) {
              console.error('Error reading image dimensions:', error);
            }
          }

          console.log('setting filePath = ', decodedPath); // Log decoded path
          return {
            filename: path.basename(decodedPath), // Use `filename`
            filepath: decodedPath,
            filetype: fileType,
            dimensions, // Include dimensions if available
          };
        })
      );

      event.sender.send('selected-file-paths', fileInfoArray);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error opening file dialog:', error);
  }
});

Log output:
normalizedPath =  E:\martinradio\upload\Casselberry-DuPre├⌐ ΓÇô City Down\B2 - War.flac
decodedPath =  E:\martinradio\upload\Casselberry-DuPre∩┐╜ ‼ City Down\B2 - War.flac
setting filePath =  E:\martinradio\upload\Casselberry-DuPre∩┐╜ ‼ City Down\B2 - War.flac


My code lives here:
https://github.com/MartinBarker/electron-ghactions/blob/3e9f61b6a1eaab7f4cca6c2a92e769320af04926/main.js#L162
